# Change owner to all tables with PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I want change owner for all tables in specific table_catalog with function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function change_owner_table_catalog(catalog_arg varchar, owner_arg varchar)
    RETURNS void AS $$
    DECLARE
    table_name_value varchar;
    sequence_name_value varchar;
    BEGIN
        for table_name_value in (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_catalog = catalog_arg) loop
            ALTER TABLE table_name_value OWNER TO owner_arg;
        end loop;
    END;
    $$ language plpgsql;
```

I execute it:

```
select change_owner_table_catalog('cinema', 'cinema_user')
```

And have the next error:

> ERROR:  relation "table_name_value" does not exist
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "ALTER TABLE table_name_value OWNER TO owner_arg"
> PL/pgSQL function change_owner_table_catalog(character varying,character varying) line 7 at SQL statement
> SQL state: 42P01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL, since `ALTER TABLE` does not support parameters:

```
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE public.%I OWNER TO %I', table_name_value, owner_arg);
```